# Using BCP to output file as ANSI as UTF-8 MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bcp

I have MSSQL 2012 Server database table with International characters. 
Is there any way I can bcp out the table into csv file in *UTF-8* format?

When i tring to pass code page 65001 to `bcp` command it throws me error:

```
SQL 2012 does not support UTF-8. This code page (65001) is supported from SQL  2016.

Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]This version of SQL Server Native Client does not support UTF-8 encoding (code page 65001)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found solution to run after `BCP` command Powershell script:

Just run

```
PowerShell -Command "Get-Content .\$FILE.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $FILE.utf8.txt "
```

Answer (score 1):

Code page **65001** does not support for SQL Server 2012 (only for SQL Server 2016 and higher, **Important Versions prior to SQL Server 2016 (13.x) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding).** from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql). You can use Unicode **1200** page and then manually convert file to preferred code page.

Also I recommend to use my stored procedure [usp_bcpTableUnload](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Stored_Procedure/dbo.usp_bcpTableUnload.sql) that have some improvements: save table column names to first row, make data sorting and others nice features.